# Intersection of two functions, logarithms

Tags: logarithms

I have to calculate the intersections of the two following functions:

(i) f(x) = $3^x$ and $g(x) = 2^{-x}$
(ii) f(x) = $e^{-x}$ and $g(x) = 2e^x$

and I must do a mistake somewhere but I don't know where.

For (i) I simply get $x \log3 = -x \log2$ and hence $x(\log3-\log2) = 0$, so the intersection is at x=0?
And for (ii) I get $\log(e^{-x}) = \log(2e^x)$ and hence $-x = \log2+x*\log e$ which then results in $0 = log2$. Where are my mistakes?

Comment: For (i), you're right.  For (ii), you made an algebra mistake.  $-x = \log 2 + x \log e = \log 2 + x$, so $-2x=\log 2$, or $x=-\frac{1}{2}\log 2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(i)$ There is no mistake in your work here: $x = 0$ is correct.

$(ii)$ Your work up to and including this statement is correct: $-x = \log2+x\log e$. I think you made mistakenly canceled the $x$ terms on each side of the equation.

$$
\begin{align}
- x & = \log2+x\log e \\ \\ 
- x& = \log 2 + x \\ \\
 -2x & = \log 2 \\ \\ 
x & = -\frac 12\cdot \log 2
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Very clear description using the OP post! +1